# How can I find how many days apart two Dates are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ActiveRecord model with some attributes stored in MySQL as `DATE`s. In Ruby, they appear as `Date`s.

How can I discover how many days apart they are, assuming like March 3, 2011 is one day apart from March 4, 2011, two days apart from March 5, etc.

Also, I need to find out how many days apart they are from the current date.

Comment: What are you trying to do with those distances?  ActiveSupport has a [very large number of more focused date/time helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html) that might solve your underlying problem

Comment: Thanks. Good to know for future ref.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `distance_of_time_in_words` helper:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(date1, date2)
```

If you want greater accuracy, I wrote a gem called [`dotiw`](http://github.com/radar/dotiw) which would allow something like this:

```
distance_of_time_in_words(date1, date2, false, :only => ["days"]
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking around a little more I came up with this...

```
(obj.arrival_date - obj.departure_date).floor.abs
 # => How many days apart.
```

And...

```
(obj.arrival_date - Date.today).floor.abs
```

Based on experimentation, it seems to work, although I'm not 100 percent sure it will always be correct.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.new(2001,2,3) - Date.new(1999,2,3)`

will give number of days